# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Categorias'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema com o `dropdownlist`. Eu populei ele com informações que estavam em meu DB.

Código da *controller*:

```
    public ActionResult NovoProduto()
    {
        ViewBag.categorias = new SelectList(db.Categoria, "CategoriaId", "Nome");
        return View();
    }
```

ele carrega na *view* tudo certo. Estou recebendo na *view* desta forma:

```
@Html.DropDownList("categorias", "selecione uma categoria")
```

só que quando eu faço uma ação, exemplo, cadastrar um novo produto, e tenho um return para a tela em que existe o dropdownlist ele dá erro.

> "{"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Categorias'."}"

Só que não faço ideia do porquê do erro, pois não muda nada quando retorna: eu apenas adicionei algo em uma tabela que não tem nada a ver com a da lista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cada vez que se dá um return, você deve repopular sua *ViewBag* novamente.

Então, se você tem esse *endpoint* para abrir o *form* de "Produto Novo":

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NovoProduto()
{
    ViewBag.categorias = new SelectList(db.Categoria, "CategoriaId", "Nome");
    return View();
}
```

Deve ter a mesma lógica após o **POST** do formulário:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NovoProduto(Produto produto)
{
    // Salva o produto ...

    // Popula a ViewBag novamente
    ViewBag.categorias = new SelectList(db.Categoria, "CategoriaId", "Nome");
    return View();
}
```